# Why does the output voltage from 180W ATX PSU on +12V rail deliver only +9.6V to +9.7V?

Tags: ac, dc, switch-mode-power-supply, atx

I recently got three ATX PSUs which I plan to use as bench supplies. I've successfully managed to get one of them (250W) converted and running as bench supply. But the other two a 150W and 180W. The former only has a click when I power it up and has no output voltage nor does the fan spin.

Now the third 180W PSU is the one my question is related to. I shorted the GREEN and BLACK wires and the PSU fan is spinning and the out put on +5V and 3.3V rails are 4.9V and 3.4V respectively. But on the +12V rail the output is only 9.7V and when I connect a load (CPU fan) on the +12V rail it did not run and the PSU shut after like 10 sec.

I even tried connecting it to my UPS and it is when I noticed that the "SITE FAULT WIRING" LED came ON. Anyone has any idea what could be the possible issue here.I know there is high voltage and precaution needs to be taken so if its a small issue that I can rectify I'm planning to rectify it by myself.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: where did you source these units? It could very well be they are just broken...

Comment: Maybe , not sure if it was discarded coz its damaged. Actually got it from some old PCs. All three where Pentium 4 so I only salvaged the PSU and Heatsink from them. All three are Dell PSUs. Luckily one is working fine but it is too large. The other two are small and compact that is why I wanted to see if its possible to repair if its a minor issue.

Comment: In that case it's very conceivable that it's broken. In most cases, what breaks are the electrolytic capacitors, which you should be able to replace. Ofcourse, as always, computer PSU's are kinda horrible in terms of noise performance because they rely on the motherboard regulators to get a nice voltage. Output ripple on the order of 100's of mV is not unheard of, especially in old, cheap units.

Comment: Thanks. So , I'll take a look at the caps today and see if its given up the ghost. If the caps are blown it means it will damage the power transistor, right? Also what are some of the possible components I should look at if the cap is okay? If there is a blown IC I guess its best to just remove some useful components and throw the rest.

Comment: If it's not some obviously faulty capacitors it's probably not worth spending the time and effort to diagnose and fix, given the cost of new supplies.

Comment: These units may also need a minimum load in order to regulate correctly. Try putting something on the outputs to draw, say, 500mA from each one. What does the PWR_OK pin show?

Comment: @Finbarr Yes I tried without load and the fan spins but with dummy load of 20 ohms on +5V rail it shuts down after 3-5 secs. I'll check the power okay and post the results.

Comment: It does sound broken, personally I'd just bin it :)

Comment: salvage the heatsinks and maybe bridge rectifiers and movs...